# How to add a new column in pandas Dataframe if the string or object value of column 1 is repeated in three consecutive rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say, I have a dataframe like this,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['p1305', 'p1305', 'p1305', 'p1307', 'p1307', 'p1307', 'p1301', 'p1301', 'p1301', 'p1340', 'p1340', 'p1340','P569','P987','P569']})
```

I need to add a column y if the values in ID are the same for three consecutive rows, then add yes in column y. Otherwise, add no.

Here is what I have tried,

```
# create a rolling window of size 3
rolling = df['ID'].rolling(3)

# apply a custom function to the rolling window to check if all values are the same
df['y'] = rolling.apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if all(x == x[0]) else 'No')
```

However, the above code is throwing the following error,

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

The final desired output would be:

```
  ID        y
0   p1305  Yes
1   p1305  Yes
2   p1305  Yes
3   p1307  Yes
4   p1307  Yes
5   p1307  Yes
6   p1301  Yes
7   p1301  Yes
8   p1301  Yes
9   p1340  Yes
10  P1340  Yes
11  P1340  Yes
```

Any suggestions or help are much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example for which the values would **NOT** give True?

Comment: Updated the question, with additional values in column ID which are **not**  a pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trick the method and convert to a number first, for exampe using [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) (or a `Categorical`):

```
df['y'] = (
 pd.Series(pd.factorize(df['ID'])[0], index=df.index)
   .rolling(3, min_periods=1).apply(lambda s: s.iloc[1:].eq(s.iloc[0]).all())
   .astype(bool)
)
```

Output:

```
       ID      y
0   p1305   True
1   p1305   True
2   p1305   True
3   p1307  False
4   p1307  False
5   p1307   True
6   p1301  False
7   p1301  False
8   p1301   True
9   p1340  False
10  p1340  False
11  p1340   True
```

Another approach if you want True in **all the rows of the group**, would be to use:

```
group = df['ID'].ne(df['ID'].shift()).cumsum()
df['y'] = df.groupby(group)['ID'].transform('size').eq(3) # or .ge(3)
```

Output:

```
       ID     y
0   p1305  True
1   p1305  True
2   p1305  True
3   p1307  True
4   p1307  True
5   p1307  True
6   p1301  True
7   p1301  True
8   p1301  True
9   p1340  True
10  p1340  True
11  p1340  True
```

Comment: The index 3 & 4 must be also True. Not false. In fact, all the values of the column ID have a repeating pattern of three same values.

Comment: @user1017373 Yes, I saw your edited output after posting, see my edit ;)